# How do I use getline to output a string n times using getline?

Tags: c++, getline

I want to use this code with the `getline` function to output a string `n` times, but it only outputs blank lines instead of some string. Why is this so and how do I fix it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    string str;
    getline(cin, str);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << str <<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "But it doesn't work", I'm really sorry, but from this I cannot judge what happens or doesn't happen. Please be more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you enter a number to assign a value to n, do you then enter the string after a line break? If so, str is assigned a newline character instead of the corresponding string.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
        
int main()
{
int n;
cin >> n;
string str;
// getline(cin, str);//Filter newline character
// getline(cin, str);
getline(cin.ignore(1,'\n'), str);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
cout << str <<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Rather use [`std::ws`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/ws) for skipping white space.

Comment: Need to skip newlines. Changed to use cin.ignore to skip

Comment: When you input "3  " (three blank blank newline), it will skip one blank and read blank newline as `str`.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you want the first non-whitespace text after your numeric input. You can skip leading whitespace with [`std::ws`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/ws)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    std::string str;
    std::getline(std::cin >> std::ws, str);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        std::cout << str << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```